# Multiple Custom Cells for multiple different table views

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am designing music application for iPhone. In that i have different view controller consisting of artist , albums , songs and Then further many views like that but problem i am facing is i have custom cells for each of these views so my question is do I need to Create Custom Classes for custom Cell for each different View Controller for like 10 View Controller , 10 different Custom Classes for Custom cells .My custom cell would be contain same elements for all the views or is their any shortcut or simple way of implementing multiple same custom cells. Am i making any sense at all?

Comment: Try to "group" different custom cells together. The ones that seems similar.

Comment: Do you have example images of what the cells look like / how common / similar they are to each other?

Comment: 3 Labels (songs , artist , album) , 1 Imageview from album art and 1 label to show Duration of song

Comment: I dont understand how to group. Can you plz tell me how can i group ? Custom Cells Would have same look in all different View Controllers only the content in them might change.

Comment: I know we have to have to make custom Classes for custom cell but do i need to make 10 different custom classes for custom cell for each different view controllers?